# Reputation gain greater than actual rep

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

How can I have reputation change greater than my reputation?[image: screenshot]

What is the "change" field even for?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's the *rank* change, not the rep change.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "+3579" in your screenshot is the *change in rank*, not the change in reputation. Therefore, prior to the last "tick" of the list (I think in that case it's weekly), your rank was around 4.5k - you have moved up 3579 ranks to the new rank of 1080.

The reputation change is only shown with the "week reputation" column and the such.

Comment: I always wondered what that meant; it's really not clear from the UI. Thanks for clearing that up.